# ngFor is triggering mouseenter on child change

Tags: angular, mouseevent

NgFor is triggering mouseenter on parent element every time the child element changes. I want to disable this behaviour but I don't know how. I created a simple example in stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qb7ez3?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  visible;
  mouseenterCalled = 0;
  intervalCalled = 0;

  items$ = interval(2000).pipe(
    map(() => {
      this.intervalCalled++;
      return [`item${this.intervalCalled}`, 'item2', 'item3'];
    })
  );

  onEnter() {
    this.mouseenterCalled++;
    this.visible = true;
  }
}
```

and the template:

```
<div (mouseenter)="onEnter()">Hover me | mouseenter was called: {{mouseenterCalled}}x | | interval was called:
  {{intervalCalled}}x</div>
<div *ngIf="visible" (mouseenter)="onEnter()">
  <div>Overlay header</div>
  <div *ngIf="items$ | async as items">
    <p *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

If you hover over `Hover me` text, the "overlay" will appear. Since the items are generated through interval, they will appear a bit later, but this is ok. Once they're there, hover over the first item. The mouseenter count will increase on every item change, but the listener itself is located on the parent div, not on the item. I've tried with stopPropagation, but it won't help. The events are still triggered. Any idea how could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adding trackBy function to ngFor

**component.html**

```
<div (mouseenter)="onEnter()">Hover me | mouseenter was called: {{mouseenterCalled}}x | | interval was called:
  {{intervalCalled}}x</div>
<div *ngIf="visible" (mouseenter)="onEnter()">
  <div>Overlay header</div>
  <div *ngIf="items$ | async as items">
    <p *ngFor="let item of items;trackBy: trackBy">{{ item }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
 trackBy = (item,index)=>{
    return item;
 }
```